# Print day of week for program when input is given?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am using switch case statements, I have to print day of the week after some given inputs in the format of year/month/day. Here is the class that is done so far and what I have done for the `printDayOfWeek()` method in the `Date` class:

```
class Date {

    int year, month, day;
    Date(int y, int m, int d) {
        year = y;
        month = m;
        day = d;
    }


    public int getDayOfWeek() {

        int y0 = year - (14 - month) / 12;
        int x = y0 + y0 / 4 - y0 / 100 + y0 / 400;
        int m0 = month + 12 * ((14 - month) / 12) - 2;
        int d0 = (day + x + (31 * m0) / 12) % 7;

        return d0;
    }

    public int getDaysInMonth(int month) {

        int daysInMonth = (int) (28 + (Math.floor(month / 8.0) + month) % 2 + 2 % month + 2 * Math.floor(1.0 / month));

        if (month == 2 && isLeapYear()) {
            daysInMonth += 1;
        }
        return daysInMonth;
    }


    public boolean isLeapYear() {


        boolean isLeapYear = true;

         if (year % 4 != 0) {
        isLeapYear = false;
    }
    else {  
        if (year % 100 != 0) {
            isLeapYear = true;
        }
        else if (year % 400 != 0) {
            isLeapYear = false;
        }
    else { 
            isLeapYear = true;
         }
    }
        // Task I.1

        return isLeapYear;
    }

    public void printDaysInMonth() {

        // Task I.2
    for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        int m = getDaysInMonth(i);

        System.out.println( i + "         " + m);
    }
}

    public void printDaysInYear() {

        // Task II

    }

    public void printDayOfWeek() {

        // Task III
         int d0 = getDayOfWeek();

         switch(d0) {
             case 1:
                 System.out.println("Monday");
             case 2:
                 System.out.println("Tuesday");
             case 3:
                 System.out.println("Wednesday");
             case 4:
                 System.out.println("Thursday");
             case 5:
                 System.out.println("Friday");
             case 6:
                 System.out.println("Saturday");
             case 7:
                 System.out.println("Sunday");
         }

    }


}
```

What is wrong with my Prinddayofweek method?
dont really know what to do at that point since am new to switch cases.

Comment: Could you provide code that resides in your main method? This is the starting point of your application

Comment: At the end of every case there must be `break;` otherwise one continues with the next case (1 will print all days).

Comment: Also mind that modulo, `%7` delivers the remainder by integer division, so 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. So the switch would go over that range.

Comment: I can't find the question? just the assignment - and one of the close reasons is: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem** or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: Ok I understand what you saying am new to this site was suggested to see if can get help here so sorry about the lack of concise question the output is supposed to be what day would it be once someone gives the date e.g. 2018 9 9 and from that must find what specific day it is.

Comment: If you want to fetch day from "year/month/day" then int day = Integer.ParseInt("2018/9/18".split("/")[2])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your printDayOfWeek() function should look like:- as you are doing %7 Sundays will have value 0. In addition to that put break; at end of each sys out to stop the flow of execution.

```
public void printDayOfWeek() {

        // Task III
         int d0 = getDayOfWeek();

         switch(d0) {
             case 0:
                 System.out.println("Sunday");
                 break;
             case 1:
                 System.out.println("Monday");
                 break;
             case 2:
                 System.out.println("Tuesday");
                 break;
             case 3:
                 System.out.println("Wednesday");
                 break;
             case 4:
                 System.out.println("Thursday");
                 break;
             case 5:
                 System.out.println("Friday");
                 break;
             case 6:
                 System.out.println("Saturday");
                 break;
         }

    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for that didnt realise to start at 0 and didnt even add the break. can not believe i missed this and was stuck on this for so long. thank you very much mate.